# How to retrieve the data from the event that triggered current event?

Tags: jquery

First I put a list of div

```
<div class=grades> Grade: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 </div>
<div class=classes> Classes numbers depend on the grade </div>
<div class=students> Students names depend on the grade and class </div>
```

And each grade number is defined like:

```
<a href=# class=gradenum>1</a>
<a href=# class=gradenum>2</a>
<a href=# class=gradenum>3</a>
.....
```

Then I try to use jquery to show the class numbers by clicking the grade number.

```
$("a.gradenum").click(function(){
  var grade = $(this).text();
  $("div#classes").load("ShowClasses.php",{'grade':grade});
});
```

It works as expected.  The classes are showed in the similar format.  Now I would like to use the same process to show the students name by the given grade and class number.

```
$("div#classes").on("click", "a.classnum",function(){
  var class = $(this).text();
  var grade = ??????  //How do I get the grade number here?
  $("div#students").load("ShowStudents.php",{'grade':grade, 'class':class});
});
```

How do I get the grade number from the number I first clicked in the grades row.

Comment: You could store the selected grade in a variable and use that in the classes event.

Comment: In your code you should have div.classes, not div#classes. Your trying to identify a class, not an id. You have nothing storing the grade number as far as I can tell. What does the link for that look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method.

```
$(".classes").on("click", ".classnum", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var class = $this.text();
  var grade = $this.index() + 1; // Start at 0
  $(".students").load("ShowStudents.php",{'grade':grade, 'class':class});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var grade; // Move this outside, making it "global".

$("a.gradenum").click(function(){
  grade = $(this).text(); // Set the global grade
  $("div.classes").load("ShowClasses.php",{'grade':grade});
});

$("div.classes").on("click", "a.classnum",function(){
  var class = $(this).text();
  // Use the global grade.
  $("div#students").load("ShowStudents.php",{'grade':grade, 'class':class});
});
```